# I have got an invalid json error

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

code :

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Error message :

```
Uncaught Invalid JSON: {times: [{'9:30am','10:00am','10:30am','11:00am','11:30am','12:00pm','12:30pm','1:00pm','1:30pm','2:00pm','2:30pm','3:00pm','3:30pm','4:00pm','4:30pm','5:00pm'}]}
```

I have tried to parse as json at Ajax,

then I don't understand why this error is appeared.

Please tell me about it.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the rest of your code.

Comment: `{'9:30am','10:00am'` is invalid JSON (and `times` should be quoted). Remove the curly braces surrounding your times.

Comment: Where does the JSON come from? It doesn't seem to be valid

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `{}` around the array's contents, and use double-quotes around the strings. Your JSON should be:

```
{"times":["9:30am","10:00am"......]}
```

Comment: don't forget that double-quotes are required around the key names as well. should be `"times"`.

Comment: single and doubles quotes are interchangable in most JSON parsers

Comment: @RobertSlaney Yes, most (good) systems are programmed on the basis of "be strict in what you send and tolerant in what you receive". That doesn't mean it's valid just because most parsers accept it.